# Can't generate APK Release because of GCM SenderId Android

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, lint

I have implemented GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) in my app. Google Play Services library has auto-generated `values.xml` in which my `senderId` is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="gcm_defaultSenderId">123</string>
</resources>
```

The problem is that I have other locale, and Lint during App Release is giving me an error : 
`Error:(3) Error: "gcm_defaultSenderId" is not translated in "fr" (French) [MissingTranslation]`

Because it is automaticaly generated I can't set `translable = false`. How I should fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume that you are using Android Studio.

Had the exact same problem with Android Studio 1.4.

First thing I tried was to edit the "File - Settings - Editor - Inspections - Android Lint - Incomplete Translation" Severity Setting to something other then 'Error'.

That did **not** help! I still was not able to build a release APK.

I ended up 'translating' the XML as follows:

1. in the folder *.../android/res* create a new language folder *values-de* (replace de with your language code).
2. create a file named google-services.xml in the language folder.
3. Insert into the xml file:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <resources>
     <string name="gcm_defaultSenderId"><YOUR_SENDERID></string>
   </resources>
   ```

   After that I was able to build the release.

Comment: There is an issue filed for this: https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=733. Please star it, so it is noticed and fixed.

Comment: The issue is [fixed since `2.0.0-alpha3`](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=195824) if you don't mind using the alpha channel. I can confirm it WFM with `2.0.0-alpha6`

Answer (score 15):

Add a `lint.xml` file in your project application root (under app/) and add the missing translations to be ignored there:

```
<lint>
    <issue id="MissingTranslation">
        <ignore regexp="ga_trackingId"/>
        <ignore regexp="gcm_defaultSenderId"/>
        <ignore regexp="google_app_id"/>
    </issue>
</lint>
```

These will now be ignored by lint - you can configure which properties to ignore, and you won't have to wait for updates from the google-services team for properties that they haven't thought of.

Lint-ing will still catch all other errors, so you can still enjoy the other features.

Comment: Works perfect as described. This seems like the most correct solution to me. Straight to the point and not a hack as some of the other answers here. Hint: put the lint.xml in the app/ folder.

Comment: @Thanos Make sure that the lint.xml file is in the correct location - I deploy from this configuration a couple of times a week without any other special handling in Android Studio

Comment: @MatsLindh I tried it a couple of times but it did not work. The only solution that I found working for me is to disable translation on build. sample `lintOptions { disable 'MissingTranslation' }` Thank you for your time and effort to assist me.

Comment: @Thanos See https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/improving-w-lint.html for examples on how to run lint manually - that might be helpful in finding out why it's failing. I strongly recommend keeping the warnings, as it _will_ catch errors while packaging.

Comment: @MatsLindh I will take a look, thanks again for providing the link and information on how to proceed.

Answer (score 3):

Since the last update of Android Studio (1.5) I had this issue too. I solved it by updating the Google Services dependencies to the [latest version](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/#set-up-your-project).

According to this [link](https://github.com/grazies/analytics-issues/issues/733#issuecomment-160963401), indeed,

> This issue should be fixed with 8.3.0 Google Play Services and 1.5.0-beta2 dependency.

Hope this helps! :)

---

**EDIT** Integration: actually, while the `gcm_defaultSenderId` string is now generated correctly (with `translatable="false"` attribute), `google_app_id` and `ga_trackingID` strings, for instance, are not.

For those still having issues, I came to the conclusion that we have to wait for Google guys to fix this issue and ignore the error in the meantime by adding to the app level `build.gradle` file

```
...
android {
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

you will probably have another bit of autogenerated code like this:

```
String token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId),
                    GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
```

Get a valid sender id from the google cloud console then you can remove the R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId from the above code and also the gcm_defaultSenderId from the resource file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want/need upgrade to newer version of:

- lint (androidstudio with build-in lint)
- build tools
- compileSdkVersion
- gradle plugin
- gradle
- google-services (plugin)
- google-services dedendencies (e.g. play-services-gcm)
- (unfortunatelly) other dependencies if are transitivelly dependent to google-services

you need to choose wiselly versions of all these parts together. Since these all needs to be compatible together. Unfortunatelly, there is no compatibility table (the only I found is more a year old, so I do not link it here. If anybody know any please share a link).

So, solution is investigate which verstion of which part blocks anything else.  Which could be nightmare, so a lot of advice is to revert to last known funcional configuration. But sooner or later we will be force to upgrade.

I checked home pages of each part to find any version info, but at last I still solve it by test-and-try method.

Here is what is functional for me:

- androidstudio 1.5
- build tools 23.0.2
- compileSdkVersion 23
- gradle plugin 1.5.0
- gradle 2.8
- google services plugin 1.5.0
- google services dependencies 8.3.0
- lucky, no other external GS dependencies (obviously all internal modules needs to use same version)