# Lint complains about not translated gcm_defaultSenderId string

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services, release, android-lint

I've followed the tutorial https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client. It works - I'm able to send and receive notifications.

But when I try to build release app, Android Lint complains:

```
Error: "gcm_defaultSenderId" is not translated in ...
```

So I can disable build failing when Lint complains with this in `build.gradle`:

```
lintOptions{
    abortOnError false
}
```

But obviously this is not a solution. Hardcoding `senderId` in my app is also not good idea (we have valid `gcm_defaultSenderId` anyway in the `google-services.json` so doubling it is asking for problems in the future).

**Is there any way around this obvious oversight from Google Play Services developers?**

---

EDIT 02 December 2015
OMG! Today google actuallt started doing something on this issue, [see here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=195824).

---

Disclaimer: this is not a duplicate of [Can't generate APK Release because of GCM SenderId Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32402914/cant-generate-apk-release-because-of-gcm-senderid-android/32409540#32409540) - the accepted answer is not acceptable for me.

Comment: This issue was addressed to google, still no answer, if I get one I'll post it here.

Answer (score 2):

I think this question actually is duplicate of [Can't generate APK Release because of GCM SenderId Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32402914/cant-generate-apk-release-because-of-gcm-senderid-android/32409540) even if I agree with your opinion about the accepted answer.

The solution is much simpler, <del>you just need to</del> update Google Services dependency version, take a look at the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33959956/5219866) I gave there for details.

---

**EDIT** The solution I gave is not sufficient to solve the issue. I thought it was OK because I'm working on a multiflavor app and, for reasons I'm still investigating, the Google Services gradle plugin generates only the `gcm_defaultSenderId` string in flavors other than the main one.

According to this [link](https://github.com/grazies/analytics-issues/issues/733#issuecomment-160963401),

> This issue should be fixed with 8.3.0 Google Play Services and 1.5.0-beta2 dependency.

But actually, while the `gcm_defaultSenderId` string is now generated correctly (with `translatable="false"` attribute), `google_app_id` and `ga_trackingID` strings are not.

**TL;DR** I came to the conclusion that we have to wait for Google guys to fix this issue and ignore the error in the meantime by adding to the app level `build.gradle` file

```
...
android {
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}
...
```

Comment: It kinda is a duplicate. But please see my question "Disclaimer: this is not a duplicate of Can't generate APK Release because of GCM SenderId Android - the accepted answer is not acceptable for me." The original question owner accepted most ridiculous answer possible so I had to create another question to gather other, hopefully correct, answers. Please update your question to actually state what need to be done and I'll check if it helps.

Comment: Anyway it did not help.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't explain well, I agree with you in the fact that the accepted answer is not the best practice to solve the problem, even not recommended in my opinion because it's just a workaround that bypasses the real problem. Actually, the day after my answer I had some other problems related to the first, other generated strings giving me problems (though the "gcm_defaultSenderId" is not among these because after the update it's generated with the "translatable" property set to false). I'm currently investigating what I can do to solve these other problems, I'll update when I find out.

Comment: After more researches I found this [link](https://github.com/grazies/analytics-issues/issues/733). Here is confirmed that the issue is fixed for `gcm_defaultSenderId` but still present for the other strings (as I experienced in first person) I came to the conclusion that we have to ignore the lint error and then try again with each new version of the com.google.gms:google-services that comes out if this is totally fixed.

Comment: Anyway I'm sorry I received a downvote, I answered on the first instance because I actually thought the issue was fixed. That happened because I'm working at a multiflavor app and, for some reasons I'm still investigating, the gradle plugin only generates `gcm_defaultSenderId` string on flavors other than the main one so I didn't notice the issue was still there until I needed to build the main flavor the next day. I'm editing my response now to make it correct.

Comment: Please check issue reported by me to google https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=195824 and update it if you know of any other strings that need special treatment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
android {
 lintOptions {
    disable 'MissingTranslation'
}
```

}